# Spectacle no longer launches

Tags: kubuntu, kde, qt

I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling Spectacle, rebooting, but no dice -- it doesn't launch from the Plasma (3.24.7) launcher, nor the command line. Some potentially useful info here though:

```
➜  ~ spectacle 
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
kf.dbusaddons: Couldn't register name 'org.kde.spectacle' with DBUS - another process owns it already!
```

ChatGPT suggests that there may be an instance already running, but when I `ps`, I don't see it.

A StackOverflow post w/ a similar error suggests perhaps I'm missing (some) Qt packages? I'm not seeing any similar posts on askubuntu nor on the web.

System info:
Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
WM: KDE Plasma 5.24.7
Kernel: 6.2.0-32-generic

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated -- thank you!

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Don't use ChatGPT for technical support questions. That is not its strength. 2) Link to other pages or posts that you refer to. 3) The error message suggests that Spectacle is already running, or has crashed. Reboot and try again.

Comment: ChatGPT has proven useufl for technical questions many times now in my experience. As I mentioned in my post, I've already tried rebooting, and ``ps`` reveals that spectacle is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the exact same issue, I used the snap installer though.
Using

```
snap install spectacle
```

caused the issue for me.

I was able to solve it, by not using the snap version but the apt package instead.
It is named `kde-spectacle`.

So the fix for me was

```
sudo snap remove spectacle
sudo apt install kde-spectacle
```

Had lots of issues with snap installs (probably due to their sandboxing) in the past.
Would always advise to use native deb package instead if possible.